# Fading modal window in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a form that is editable by the user.  Once he clicks the "Save" button, a modal window pops up saying something like "Changes saved" and then fades away automatically.  I prefer that this modal window not be able to be interacted with or grey out the background screen.

Some of the examples I see with modal windows require clicking a button to show the window but then you have to click outside the modal window to close it.  Is there a way to make it automatic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just pop-up a div and after you save the settings, do `(function(){ var mzk = $('mark_zuckenberg').show(); setTimeout(function(){mzk.fadeOut('slow')},5000); }());` and it'll do what you want.